# Why isn't using the highest z-index allowing my icon to cover a div that should go beneath it but it will not?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've searched around for other answers but can't seem to fin one specifically... I'm using z-index correctly so I don't get why this is happening. That line you see in the example is supposed to go under the icon and over the sidebar but it is not.

**I've tried so far**

1. Fiddling with the z-indexes
2. Giving the icon in question position absolute
3. placing the !important keyword on the z-index property

.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #d9d8d7;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.text-container {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.top-left-container {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
/*   position:relative; */
}

.horizontal-line {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 75%;
  left:-150%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 300%;
  z-index: ;
  background-color: black;
  /*  z-index level 2 "middle"  */
  z-index: 10;
}

.heading {
/*   background-color:yellow; */
  grid-column: 1 /-1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
/*  z-index level 1  */
  z-index: 5;
}

.sidebar__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
/*   background-color: red; */
}

.sidebar__icon {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 50;
/*  z-index level 3 Why wont'this cover the div
that has a higher z-index than it */
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
      
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">

    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="text-container">

    <div class="top-left-container">
          <div class="heading">Header Here</div>
        <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read up on stacking contexts. https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are four things about z-index:

1. the lower in the code the higher the placement
2. adding a transform or opacity will give new z-index context (meaning higher yet again)
3. positioning an element will do the same as number 2
4. And lastly, as is in your case, a child element will inherit and be limited by its parent element if its parent element has a z-index set

The solutions:

1. Either take the child div out, and make it a sibling to the competing z-index div on the page (in your case that line) *recommended
2. Remove z-index context on parent element, so child again can be free

Comment: This worked thanks. My parent sidebar definitely had z-index: 1;

Answer (score 0):

Give the element you want to stand out one more `z-index`

I added  z-index `.sidebar__wrapper` class more then `.horizontal-line` class

```css
     .container {
          background-color: #d9d8d7;
          width: 600px;
          height: 500px;
          display: grid; 
          grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
          grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
          grid-gap: 5px;
        }

        .text-container {
          background: pink;
          grid-column: 3 / -1;
          grid-row: 1 / 3;
          display: grid;  
          grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
          grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
          grid-gap: 5px;
        }

        .top-left-container {
          grid-column: 1 / 4;
          grid-row: 1 / 4;
          position: relative;
          background-color: orange;
        /*   position:relative; */
        }

        .horizontal-line {
          position: absolute; 
          bottom: 75%;
          left:-150%;
          height: 2px;
          width: 300%;
          background-color: black;
          /*  z-index level 2 "middle"  */
          z-index:10;
        }

        .heading {
        /*   background-color:yellow; */
          grid-column: 1 /-1;
          grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .sidebar {
          background-color: lightblue;
          grid-row: 1 / -1;
          grid-column: 1 / 2;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: start;
          align-items: center;
        /*  z-index level 1  */
         
        }

        .sidebar__wrapper {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
           z-index: 11;
        /*   background-color: red; */
        }

        .sidebar__icon {
          margin: 10px;
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          z-index: 50;
        /*  z-index level 3 Why wont'this cover the div
        that has a higher z-index than it */
          z-index: 15;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="container">
          
          <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
              
                    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">
                    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">
                    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/images-icons-rounded/110/Image-Focus-512.png" alt="" class="sidebar__icon">

            </div>    
          </div>
          
          <div class="text-container">

            <div class="top-left-container">
                  <div class="heading">Header Here</div>
                <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't go under the icon and over the sidebar.

Comment: I edited for you. @OsianMansell